# Can't disable all breakpoints in firefox

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, javascript-debugger

According to this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Disable_breakpoints), in Firefox I should be able to click on the following icon in the debugger to disable all breakpoints

[image]

Unfortunately, I don't have this icon in my Firefox:

[image]

I'm using Firefox 57 and it makes writing and debugging javascript extremely difficult. Is this a feature that has to be enabled somewhere? Am I doing something else wrong?

**Note**: I'm not interested in using Chromium as an alternative

Comment: When you set a couple breakpoints, you'll notice that a checkbox will appear next to the word "Breakpoints". Toggleing that toggles all breakpoints.

Comment: In your screenshot you haven't set any breakpoints. So the question is, have you tried setting any? Maybe that button appears only if you have already set at least one.

Comment: I know this box, unfortunately this doesn't help with breakpoints set in the code with a `debugger;` statement.

Comment: @nisarg I'm using `debugger;`-Statements in the code. See my previous comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that they have removed this button. I ran into this problem today and I came across:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1184328

This is the only place I have seen mentioned that this was removed. I have not found any reason for this change though.

Comment: The breakpoints checkbox mentioned in the link is only visible if you've set breakpoints in code (debugger statements don't count as breakpoints, unfortunately), and the debugger still stops on `debugger;` statements. I hope you're wrong because firefox debugging is broken if you're not :(

Comment: This exactly was addressed in your link. I'd prefer to use firefox, but it seems to be irreparably broken. Chromium is the only develpment browser left. :((((

Comment: Ok, I've seen firefox in various operating systems, and this icon is gone in all of them, so I consider this question answered.